# Rewrite float into BigDecimal

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bigdecimal

I want to calculate values from Java List. I managed to create the code using float in order to store money amount.

```
    private float sumAmounts(List<ExpressCheckout> myList)
    {
        float total = 0.0f;
        for (ExpressCheckout item : myList)
        {
            total += item.getAmount();
        }
        return total;
    }
```

I tried this code:

```
private BigDecimal sumAmounts(List<ExpressCheckout> myList)
{
    BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ZERO);
    for (ExpressCheckout item : myList)
    {
//            total += item.getAmount();
        total.add(item.getAmount());

    }
    return total;
}
```

But I get NPE when I execute the code. Is this a proper way to use BigDecimal?

Comment: The NPE appears to have nothing to do with BigDecimal and all to do with your code throwing a NPE. Do you know how to debug NPE's? If not, search for the canonical question/answer on this, and debug your program first.

Comment: Either `myList` or one of the `item`s is `null`. What line produces the NPE?

Comment: NPE link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Where do you get the NPE?

Comment: FWIW, it should be `total = total.add(item.getAmount());`, assuming this `getAmount()` returns a *BigDecimal*. *BigDecimals* are immutable, so add returns a *new* instance of *BigDecimal*. This must be assigned to. I doubt this causes your NPE, though.